# pandas dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a big .csv file that I'm reading into a pandas dataframe.  Then I loop through the file and once I find the values I'm looking for I use the dataR = df.append(data).  There are 2 columns in the .csv file that I read one of the (column A ) where the values go from 1 to 3 and then it repeats again from 1 to 3 and again like this: Notice that column B does not repeat.

```
+-----+---+---+--+--+
|     | A | B |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 288 | 1 | 4 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 245 | 2 | 3 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 543 | 3 | 6 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 867 | 1 | 9 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 345 | 2 | 7 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 122 | 3 | 8 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 233 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 346 | 2 | 6 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
| 765 | 3 | 3 |  |  |
+-----+---+---+--+--+
```

What I want to do is instead of appending the values as rows I would like to append them as columns like this:

```
+-----+---+---+-----+
|     | A | B | C   |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 288 | 1 | 4 | 9   |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 245 | 2 | 3 | 7   |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 543 | 3 | 6 | 8   |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 867 |NaN| 9 | 1   |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 345 |NaN| 7 | 6   |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 122 |NAN| 8 | 3   |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 233 |NaN| 1 | NaN |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 346 |NaN| 6 | NaN |
+-----+---+---+-----+
| 765 |NaN| 3 | NaN |
+-----+---+---+-----+
```

Is there a flag to set for this?  dataR = df.append(data, flag=?)

Thanks

Comment: This question would be helped with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use **concat** with ***axis=1*** instead of **append**.
See examples [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).